# Longest match in a Mongodb list

Tags: python, mongodb

Say we have a following in the Mongo

```
{joe: { 
    grocerylist: [ 
      { "activity" : "buy", "type" : "cheese-cheddar" }, 
      { "activity" : "dontbuy", "type" : "cheese-pepperjack" },
      { "activity" : "buy", "type" : "cheese" }
   ]}
{joanna: { 
    grocerylist: [ 
      { "activity" : "buy", "type" : "cheese-cheddar" }, 
      { "activity" : "buy", "type" : "cheese" }
   ]}
```

When Joe queries for "cheese-pepperjack", it should result in his "dontbuy" list. Now when Jonna queries for "cheese-pepperjack", it should result in her "buy" list. Because, even though she didn't have cheese-pepperjack explicitly in her list, the longest match for that query was "cheese", which she can buy. Question is how to get the longest match in Mongo?

If we have the above dictionary in the python processes' memory instead of the MongoDB, then we can use a Trie implementation to get the above lookup. The Mongo's regex/$in can get me the comparison one string at a time (between my lookup and one of the cheese types of the "grocerylist") and I can iterate over the entire list, but is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: these two ("joe" and "joanna") are two different documents in mongodb?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Please try to be more clear, also you should avoid having a dynamic field's name in your documents and naming your field `list` is not a good idea here because it will shadow the built-in `list` function/class.

Comment: @user3100115. Updated the name. I'm looking for a way to perform longest-match. (This would be similar to the longest-prefix-match in networking)

Comment: @lesingerouge. Yes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case for the search, you could try this structure:

```
{
  "name": "joe",
  "activity": "buy",
  "type": "cheese-cheddar"
}
{
  "name": "joe",
  "activity": "dontbuy",
  "type": "cheese-pepperjack"
}
{
  "name": "joe",
  "activity": "buy",
  "type": "cheese"
}
{
  "name": "joanna",
  "activity": "buy",
  "type": "cheese-cheddar"
}
{
  "name": "joanna",
  "activity": "buy",
  "type": "cheese"
}
```

When someone is searching for `cheese-pepperjack`, you could split on the hyphen and create a list in Python `['cheese', 'cheese-pepperjack']` . Use the list to query :

```
db.groceries.find(
        {name:"joanna", 
         type: {$in:["cheese", "cheese-pepperjack"]}})
    .sort({"type":-1})
    .limit(1)
```

The query above will search for any `type` with the values of 'cheese' or 'cheese-pepperjack'. For 'joe', you may get more than one record back so you would need to sort based on `type` and limit to one record. Also, don't forget to add an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) for `type` field.

You may also be interested in:

- [Data Models Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/)
- [Model Tree Structures with Materialised Paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/)

Comment: I had looked at those links. Thx for them. Unfortunately, A) I cannot split the document in the Mongo as you had suggested. B) The names may not necessarily be hyphenated. And If I end up doing a separate Mongo lookup, then I'd rather do a radix tree lookup using values stored in process memory.